# How to set default amount of rows per page in oracle report builder?

Tags: oracle, report, rows, builder

I created report with oracle report builder and I want to fix number of rows in my report. How can I set default amount of rows per page for oracle report builder?

Answer (score 0):

In your page under your report region,

- Go to :

> REPORT ATTRIBUTE > 
>                          LAYOUT >
>                                NUMBER OF ROWS